# How to add picture BY URL using Gmail API (Chrome extension)

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I write Chrome extension and need to add a picture in the mail by URL(in js). I can't find how to do that in Gmail API documentation. The only link I found is [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads), but don`t understand how to use it(  [add picture icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emcc7.png) [add by link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuq18.png)

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is, but anyway you need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to access the page.

Comment: Yea, there is no problem with extension but with Gmail API. I can`t understand how to add a picture using it.